# Lock screen timeout on Samsung Note 4

Tags: home-button, screen-timeout, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I click the home button to activate the phone. If I don't swipe within two seconds, it goes black and I have to hit Home again.

This is frustrating when I want to just view the time and weather on the lock screen. It's almost enough time to view time and weather, but if I also want to see what date it is, then 2 seconds isn't enough time to view all three things and digest the information.

So I find myself hitting the Home button 2 or three times. So I guess I might as well just swipe and activate the phone. But I really wanted to just set the screen to stay on a little longer. I set the display timeout to 10 minutes but this doesn't affect the lock screen. It still blinks off after 2 seconds.

Is there any setting or something from a Tasker app or something, that can extend the time the lock screen will appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is apply pressure with your thumb on the screen, it will stay on forever until you lift your thumb, after which the non-adjustable timeout countdown begins...

Comment: ug. i found this question because i use a bluetooth keyboard to record thoughts during the middle of the night while using the bathroom and the tablet isn't even in the same room - i just want to make sure that during long pauses i don't have to hit enter several times to wake the darn thing back up! (i'm running a text entry field on top of the lock screen)

Comment: and i would just disable the timeout altogether when on AC power, except sometimes the device reboots or the power momentarily goes away and then it's sitting there on for hours until it wakes me up...

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether "power save" mode is on. If so, the lock screen will turn black very fast (under 2 seconds). Otherwise it will remain on for over 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Install hilocker and give it requested permissions. Go into its settings > more > select double tap dot to unlock. Cheers

Comment: Can you link this app?

Comment: I installed hi locker.not only did it NOT affect the lock screen, but I had to call Samsung for help getting it uninstalled as normal uninstall process was completely ineffective in getting app off my phone.