# Android fail to read screen timeout

Tags: samsung, 9.0-pie, screen-timeout

I use Motion Detector & Tasker to turn screen on.
It works OK ... like this:

- when screen is off and Motion Detector discovers a motion it will turn screen on.
- Tasker sets display timeout to 30 sec

Here is where it goes wrong ... the screen is not turn off after 30 sec but after 6-8 sec ... but when I tap the screen when it is turned on then it stays alive 30 sec.

I seems that Android can't read the timeout in Display settings which is 30 sec ... only when I tap the screen it reads the settings.

I have Android 9 & Galaxy Tab S5e.

Then I took another approach ....

I installed SETEDIT from Play to check the value of 'screen_off_timeout'. Then I ran two different test - one with Tasker disabled - one with Tasker enabled.

Taker disabled:

1. In 'Settings/Dislay/Screen timeout' I set to 15 sec
2. The display shutdown occured after 15 sec first time ... OK
3. When I woke the display its shutdown occured after 15 sec ... OK
4. In SETEDIT the value of 'screen_off_timeout' was 15000 ms = 15 sec
5. In 'Settings/Dislay/Screen timeout' was still 15 sec

So it seems that without Tasker it behaves as expected.

Taker enabled:

1. In 'Settings/Dislay/Screen timeout' I set to 15 sec
2. In Tasker I set 'Display Timeout' to 1 min
3. The display shutdown occured after 15 sec first time ... OK
4. When the display woke up due to a motion was detected ... its shutdown occured after 5-7 sec ... not OK
5. In SETEDIT the value of 'screen_off_timeout' was changed by Tasker to 60000 ms = 1 min ... OK
6. In 'Settings/Dislay/Screen timeout' was also changed to 1 min ... OK

So both SETEDIT & 'Settings/Dislay/Screen timeout' shows the correct values ... why is screen shut down after 5-7 sec???

Comment: There's [a lock screen timeout](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88830/44325) (which seems to be non-adjustable) that is different from the screen timeout